# How to extract componentId of the exe file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, orca

I was trying to create an msi setup for a windows form application. This msi should only installed if the local system has Access database engine 12.0 installed on it.

So I tried to put a lunch  condition in the visual studio installer. Now if I want to make this driver as a prerequisite for the new application to get installed I need COMPONENETID of this driver So that I can put a condition in launch condition.

I have and exe for Access database engine 12.0 but can't figure out the componentid of it. I tried to use ORCA tool for this prupose but ORCA tool only work with .msi not with .exe. Can someone please help me out with this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a tool like WinZip (there'a a free eval version at time of writing this) you can open that exe and WinZip will extract the files out for you without installing it. There will be an MSI file (called AceRedist.msi last time I looked) and then you can use Orca in the way you described.

Comment: I usually just spin up a clean VM, install whatever MSI is needed and then look in c:\windows\installer for the most recently touched file and off to Orca as you suggest.

Comment: AceRedist.msi is available even if Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0 is not installed. So this solution won't work.

Comment: @murari, but your question asks how to get the Component Ids that are in the Acess Database Engine, installed from Aceredist.msi, so maybe you need to rephrase the question if you don't want to know the Component Ids after all.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you are taking this approach to detect the presence of a pre-requisite? In your case, the pre-requisite here seems to be Access database engine 12.0.

IMHO, there are definitely standard ways to detect the presence of Access database engine 12.0. A simple google took me to the following link:

https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?201524-Determine-Microsoft-Database-Access-Engine-Version

Relying upon a specific component GUID from a third party vendor is definitely risky and might lead to unnecessary maintenance.